# EF6 and MVC5: Using two fields as a combined key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have several objects (Product, Rule, PriceDetail, etc.) that manage and store information in a CRUD application.  I want a way to keep a log of when the data is updated, and to that end I've created an Update class, referenced as `ICollection<Update> Updates` within each data class.

When the tables are all generated, EF creates a FK for each class in the Updates table (Product_ID, Rule_ID, etc.).  This seems horribly inefficient.  Could I use a two-field key, such as `enum ObjectType` and `long ID`?  Alternately, can I use `string ID` and force a pattern where the first N characters of the string identify the referencing object?  If the latter, can the database auto-increment the string value?

Here's some example code, trimmed for placement here:

```
public class Update
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOfUpdate { get; set; }
    public long Product_ID { get; set; }
    public long Rule_ID { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PriceDetail Price { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Update> Updates { get; set; }
}

public class Rule
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Update> Updates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why is it "horribly inefficient" ?

Comment: Maybe its not, but it **seems** that way.  If I ended up with fifty classes that were writing Updates, that would require fifty FK columns in the database, most without any data in them.  That doesn't sound well-designed to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of handling auditing logic.

1. Do you anticipate storing update history for every table? If it's going to be limited to a few tables, your design might work fine. If however, you want to update many tables, you might want to try out the options below.
2. Include 3 tables (Products, Updates and ProductUpdates). The Products tables will always have the latest data. The Updates tables will get a new row capturing the updated timestamp every time an entry in Products is updated. The ProductUpdates will have a foreign key to the Updates table and will have the old row from the Products table. This way you know exactly what the row looked at any point of time. Extending it to any other table X will require adding XUpdates table. But you wouldn't have the unnecessary 50 foreign keys that you mentioned.
3. Another option would be to have IsActive, UpdatedBy, UpdatedTimestamp, etc... columns in the tables that will be updated. Every time, you update a row, you mark it as inactive and insert a new row with the latest data. You can store the reason and rule columns also if needed.
4. You can also redesign your entities in such a way that their primary key is a foreign key to your updates table. This way you will eliminate the inelegance of all previous solutions. Every time you update, you will insert a row in the Updates table and use the generated Id as the primary key of a new row in your products table.
5. Entity Framework can help you in automating the process laid out in points 3 and 4. The basic idea would be to intercept the Save requests for updates and force an update and insert instead.
6. Lastly, you might also be able to use CLR triggers to have the audit functionality you want.

Each solution has its pros and cons. The best solution for you would depend upon your specific use case.